# How to define +/- sign in as.difftime in R?

Tags: r

I have strings representing time offsets, which have `+` and `-` signs, such as:

`string1 <- c("+00:30", "-07:00")`

How can I convert these to `as.difftime` format? I know if there were no signs, I could have just written `as.difftime(string1, format = "%H:%M")` and it will work. However, I do not know how to handle the signs. I want to use the resulted `difftime` for converting UTC time to LST.

I appreciate your time and help in advance.

Comment: Ha, I don't think it does (surprising)! You might just have to strip the sign and do some `ifelse`/`grep` fancyfooting to stick the sign back on...

Comment: There's a `gmtoff` described under `DateTimeClasses` but I've literally never seen it used. So couldn't even provide you with an example.

Comment: Thanks, I did use substr to split sign and numbers and then created the as.difftime

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to do this using `as.difftime` and the `format = "%z"` but there are a couple of issues. First, the colon isn't a valid part of a time zone specifier. Second, the output seems to be relative to your current timezone. Here's a function which gets round those:

```
tz_to_difftime <- function(x, zero = "+0000") {
  out <- as.difftime(c(zero, gsub("[: ]", "", x)),
                     format = "%z")
  out[1] - out[-1]
}
tz_to_difftime("+05:30")
```

Note that this will only work for differences of up to 14 hours in current R (less on older versions).

Here's an alternative using `strsplit`:

```
tz_to_difftime2 <- function(x) {
  as.difftime(sapply(strsplit(x, ":"),
    function(x) as.numeric(x) %*% c(1, 1/60)),
    units = "hours")
}
```

And if you like things more pipey (using `magtittr`)

```
tz_to_difftime3 <- . %>%
  strsplit(":") %>%
  sapply(
    . %>%
    as.numeric %>%
    multiply_by_matrix(c(1, 1/60))
  ) %>%
  as.difftime(unit = "hours")
```

These last two have the advantage that they'll take any number of hours.

Comment: This is the short solution borrowed from another page           as.difftime(gsub("[+-]","",x), format ="%H:%M") * ifelse(grepl("^-",x),-1,1)

Comment: @newbie I figured you'd done something along those lines, but thought it would be interesting to explore alternatives

Comment: Thanks, it is indeed helpful.